# memcpy Seg fault seemingly innoculous

Tags: c, berkeley-db, memcpy

Got a seg fault from my memcpy that gdb can't give me anything else on (at least beyond the simple manner that I know how to use gdb...). This thing is deeply imbedded in some code using the Berkely DB; I have taken out the only lines that should be of any use.

```
  void *databuf;
  int smallest;
  databuf=malloc(2*sizeof(int));
  memset(databuf,0,2*sizeof(int));



  /* This next line comes from the DB structures; key.data is a void*... */
  smallest=*(int *)key.data;

  memcpy(databuf,(void *)smallest,sizeof(int));
```

To confirm the variable smallest is correct, I can run gdb and get

```
(gdb) print smallest
$1 = 120321
```

The error I recieve (in gdb) is the useless

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08048efa in main (argc=4, argv=0xbffff344) at index_DB-1.1.c:128
128       memcpy(databuf,(void *)smallest,sizeof(int));
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x08048efa in main (argc=4, argv=0xbffff344) at index_DB-1.1.c:128
```

The reason I am doing this is mostly because I am bastardizing the Berkley DB tutorial, but also later I want to do

```
memcpy(databuf+len,(void *)largest,sizeof(int));
```

i.e. have a void pointer databuf with first byes the smallest integer and second bytes the largest integer. What am I missing?

Comment: The fact that you consider the error message to be "useless" is a big clue to what you're missing. In other words, you're "missing" the information actually provided to you by the error message. :)

Comment: haha, I'm thinking of the word "useless" in the colloquial sense. I know a seg fault likely means some kind of invalid memory entry, which is useful information... but *more* useful information would be "(void *)smallest is not a valid pointer, you idiot!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this step, you are interpreting the value in `smallest` as a pointer:

```
memcpy(databuf,(void *)smallest,sizeof(int));
```

Since that value is almost certainly *not* a valid pointer, this is causing your segfault.  Instead, you likely want:

```
memcpy(databuf, &smallest, sizeof smallest);
```

Unless you need `smallest` for some other reason though, you can just copy directly from `key.data` to to `databuf`:

```
memcpy(databuf, key.data, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: I appreciate it, even though it's a simple answer. I actually thought casting (void *) would copy the value in smallest to the memory pointed to by databuf. Shows I don't understand these things as well as I thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
(void *)smallest
```

That takes the integer value of smallest and treats it as a pointer. What you meant to do was this:

```
(void *)&smallest
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell what you're doing, considering the code is so awful, but this looks very suspicious:

```
memcpy(databuf,(void *)smallest,sizeof(int));
```

I believe `smallest` contains normal integer data, not a pointer to anything. So why are you dereferencing it? It doesn't point to anything.

You might want:

```
memcpy(databuf,(void *) &smallest,sizeof(int));
```

Also, this is suspect:

```
smallest=*(int *)key.data;
```

Is `smallest` guaranteed to be integer aligned?